# Creating buckets by comparing Dimension member against Measure using MDX

Tags: mdx

I have a Product dimension with hierarchies - product_id, initial_price, product_name and Measures - units_sold, cost_per_unit, revenue_per_unit. For each product_id I need to compare initial_price against revenue_per_unit and then assign it to a bucket based on the comparison. 


Consider the following example:
Input:
product_id  initial_price revenue_per_unit
1         10        12
2         20        18
3         30        30

Output:
product_id   bucket_name
1        Profit
2        Loss
3        Same

How can I achieve this using MDX?

Comment: How should a fourth product be displayed which is also a profit? Would you want to have a new line containing "4   Profit"? Do you really want to show product IDs with MDX, not product names?

Comment: Could you please show the MDX which produces the data that you show as "Input"? This eases answering without assuming dimension names etc., which then makes it more easy for you to use the answer.

Comment: Yes, if there is a fourth product with Profit then it should appear as a new row with values - 4 and Profit. Displaying either product_id or product_name would do for me as both are different hierarchies within the same dimension so the logic should be the same.

Comment: Should I share the schema XML containing Dimenion, Hierarchy and Level?

Comment: No, just the MDX statement producing the data that you have so far would help. I now just made up some names in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Member [Measures].[Bucket] AS
            CASE
                WHEN [Measures].[initial_price] < [Measures].[revenue_per_unit] THEN
                     "Profit"
                WHEN [Measures].[initial_price] > [Measures].[revenue_per_unit] THEN
                     "Loss"
                ELSE
                     "Same"
            END
SELECT {[Measures].[Bucket]}
       ON COLUMNS,
       [Product].[Product Name].Members
       ON ROWS
  FROM [yourcube]
```

should deliver what you want. Please note that calculated measures need not return numbers, they also can return strings in MDX (they even can return a string for some cells, and a number for others).

In case you do not have the price available as e. g. an average price on aggregated product level, and want to do the bucketing on product level, the best solution would be not do do that in MDX at all, but in the cube design: Just calculate the bucket on the relational side, and add it as an attribute to the product dimension.

You did not state anything about other dimensions, especially time. In case some other dimensions matter as well to determine the bucket, it might be necessary to add a separate dimension just for the buckets.

Comment: Initial price is just a hierarchy in my Product Dimesion and not a Measure as Initial price of each product is same and does not depend on business process.

Comment: Product Dimension has the following hierarchies:
1. Name
2. Product id
3. Initial price

Comment: Is `Initial Price` a property of product Id or name? I. e. is there a relationship from one of these to the initial price attribute?

Comment: Initial price is a hierarchy for now. But even if we assume Initial price as a Measure then also when we do a rollup at say Category level  then we want each product to be assigned into a bucket first and then do a rollups. Using the above query that you have written it will first do a sum of all initial_price and revenue_per_unit for all products in the category and then do a rollups which will result in incorrect bucketing.

Comment: @ChiragNahar I added some suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs FrankPI. As per your suggestions I think the best way is to add a separate dimension just for the buckets.